# How to append File Separator at the end of given directory path

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to append File separator at the end of a given directory path. But `os.path.join` is not appending the required separator.

I have tried the below code. Consider directoryPath = //TEAM/PATH_1/PATH_2/2018-Aug-06

```
os.path.join(directoryPath, "")
```

But the output it gives is

> //TEAM/PATH_1/PATH_2/2018-Aug-06\

So i tried the below code.

```
if(len(directoryPath.split("/")) >= 1):
  return os.path.join(directoryPath, "/")
else:
  return os.path.join(directoryPath, "\\")
```

For this output was

> //TEAM/PATH_1/

Can someone guide me the correct way to append File Separator at the end.

Comment: Why do you need the trailing separator?

Comment: That is the requirement. I am using an API which needs File Separator at the end.

Comment: Are you using this under Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.join` will use the separator for the OS you run the program on (accessible via `os.sep` variable).

If what you want is to reuse the separator from existing variable (`directoryPath`) *independently* of OS your program is running on, then you should not rely on `os` package at all - just append the string to the path.

Answer (score 1):

os.path.join automatically use the correspondence OS path separator.

If you intend to run your command in windows but want the `/` slash separator, just just `replace`.  i.e.

```
os.path.join(directoryPath, '').replace('\\', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a a slash at the end of your string?

```
>>> directoryPath = '//TEAM/PATH_1/PATH_2/2018-Aug-06'
>>> directoryPath += '/'
>>> directoryPath
'//TEAM/PATH_1/PATH_2/2018-Aug-06/'
```